# Get results from the main wp_query

Tags: posts, wp-query, filters

I would like to alter the main `wp_query` and then email the results as PDF or HTML email.

I have managed to filter `wp_query` using custom filters and some code similar to this inside my plugins function:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'foo_modify_query_exclude_category' );
function foo_modify_query_exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && ! $query->get( 'cat' ) )
    $query->set( 'cat', '-5' );

    //
    // CALL preparePDF($wp_query) here in order to prepare the PDF
    //  
}
```

The results are successfully filtered and presented to the user.

At this point (or even before presenting the results to the user I would like to do the following (I am actually trying to do this inside the same function I used to filter the main query:

I created a new function where I pass the main `wp_query` as parameter: and I try to print the results:

```
function preparePDF($wp_query) {

var_dump($wp_query);

// The Loop
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
        $wp_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
    echo 'no posts found';
}

}
```

Unfortunately even if my query seems correct when I use `var_dump`, I get no results.

Can I somehow fix this? Am I doing it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calling `preparePDF( $wp_query )` inside your callback, but `$wp_query` isn't defined and the global `$wp_query` shouldn't be accessible there without `global $wp_query`.

Try instead `preparePDF( $query )` and use [`wp_reset_postsdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) to restore the global `$post` object.

Another important thing is that you must run your `preparePDF()` function after `WP_Query` has fetched the posts from the database. So don't use the `pre_get_posts` hook, use a later hook instead. But that hook depends on what you want to do with the posts. I also don't understand what you're preparing with your `preparePDF()` function.

Remember to use `WP_DEBUG` on your dev install, to catch any PHP errors, warnings and notices. Check for example the [Debugging in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) in the Codex.

Comment: Do you believe is it better to use `the_posts` filter to get the results and prepare the pdf from there instead of calling the `wp_query`?

Comment: Btw I am not calling the global $wp_query. I am using $query which is passed by the callback and I correctly modify it. Why I am not able to call it? I mean why I am not able to use `$query->have_posts()`.

Comment: yes, no posts have been fetched within the pre_get_posts callback, we must use a later hook. But I'm not sure I undertand what you're preparing with `preparePDF()`, what are you modifying there? @glarkou

Comment: I am getting the posts and I prepare a PDF similar to what the result is in the Wordpress admin. Afterwards I email these results to the user.